Altium Designer 24: directives on schematic, yet "No differential pairs in design" error when routing
I want to create an USB differential pair. I added the nets, name equally but changing P and N as the image shows:

SCH to PCB has been updated. Project comparator is enabled. No differential pair classes appear.
When I try to route the differential pair this error shows up: "No differential pairs in design". What is happening?


Did you import changes from SCH to PCB? Does the net class show up (Design/Classes)?

Yes, I imported but nothing. In differential pair classes it doesn't apear. What can I do?

And you've done everything from this page? If nothing works then you could try creating design rules for those two traces.

Check here: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/keeping-schematics-pcb-synchronized#what-can-be-synchronized

I checked everything you said and nothing is different.

I finally found the solution. In the toolbar, select Design->Constraint manager.
Here, select Physical, right click -> Differential pairs -> Create differential pairs from nets.


That's great! The best way to keep this information in mind is by finding the solution in your way!
Please check this as answered if it did help you and answered your question

I usually do it like this,
Add a differential pair class on the schematics :

then in the stack layer, impedance :

and then define a rules of the differential pair using the previous defined calculation in the stack layer :

